# ECONNREFUSED when making a request to localhost using fetch in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, fetch

I'm getting some strange behaviour in Node when making a request to locally running server.

I have a local server listening on port 4000. When using `node-fetch` (or any other Node fetch implementation) I get an `ECONNREFUSED` error when making a request to it:

```
> fetch('http://localhost:4000')
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 345,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 5
}
> Uncaught TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5575:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5901:42 {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 4000
  }
}
```

I can happily make requests to this server using `curl` or a web browser without error (although it looks like it's trying IPv6 before IPv4):

```
$ curl localhost:4000 -v                                                                  
*   Trying ::1:4000...
* connect to ::1 port 4000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:4000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4000
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< content-length: 9
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< date: Thu, 26 May 2022 10:01:52 GMT
< server: Cowboy
< x-request-id: FvKfbzxLnVk2GewAAE9B
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

If I use the IPv4 address directly in Node it seems to work:

```
> fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000').then(r => console.log(r.status))
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 825,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 799
}
> 200
```

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Update:

As an experiment I disconnected from my local network and things work as normal once again. This leads me to think it's being caused by the manner of DNS resolution resulting from my network's dns config. But no idea why

Answer (score 28):

Put this somewhere in the beginning of your entry file:

```
import dns from 'node:dns';
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');
```

Comment: For an explanation of *why* this works, please check out [this article](https://blog.codergautam.dev/how-to-fix-econnrefused-when-making-a-request-to-localhost-using-fetch-in-node-js/#the-problem) which explains the issue & solution thoroughly.

Answer (score 8):

Some versions of node seem to resolve DNS with IPv6 first, depending on your environment.
When you set `localhost`, it tries to fetch the IPv6 address `::1` which may not be available.

You can force the DNS resolution order as suggested by tech-escape, setting a hardcoded IPv4 address (e.g. `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`) may also "fix" the issue

Open issue: https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1602

Comment: Could you tell more details about **depending on your environment**?

Comment: I do not know the details of which node version resolves to ipv6 first, on which system, but I meant that from one version of node to another one, perhaps one platform to another, it may resolve to ipv4 first, or ipv6.

Comment: Thanks, same problem on an astro project using node's fetch in ssr, and using 127.0.0.1 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what changed, but it suddenly started working for me. I was doing work with Cloudflare workers, so that `node:dns` import did not work (I think because they monkey patch it?). My suggestion is that you try just restarting your computer/container and that may fix it for you, too.