# ECONNREFUSED when fetching from localhost:3000 to localhost:8000 (Nextjs - DjangoApp)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django, fetch-api, econnrefused

When trying to make a 'POST' request using the 'fetch' node function, between the frontend and the backend (React Next.js and Django), I got an 'ECONNREFUSED' error.

Backend requests using Postman worked as expected.

Django is on port: 8000 and Next.js is on port: 3000.

It was working until I installed the XCode, Ionic and Capacitor packages (I don't really know if they are the reason I'm getting this error).

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/account/login.js:18:28)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:185:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:395:9)
    at async Object.fn (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:496:37)
    at async Router.execute (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:226:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:606:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:450:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/tomas.leblanc/Dev/HermesApp/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:321:20) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 8000
  }
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me dealing with this error!

If you need more details or project files, please fill free to ask :D

EDIT1:

If I start the front app, and try to execute the fetch function, it will show the above arrero, but first is gonna show this:

```
(node:10488) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Shouldn't be the reason though.

EDIT2:

I did downgrade Node.js version from 'v18.11.0' to 'v16.17.1' and now is working!!

Comment: Are you sure that the Django server is running?

Comment: Yes! Server running and receiving manual requests from Postman

Answer (score 9):

I seems I'm facing the same issue, and it looks related to IP6. I can see you're using IP6 in your stacktrace: `address: '::1'`

Apparently there is a issue with IP6 in nodejs above version 16.
I think triggered by this change: https://www.reddit.com/r/ipv6/comments/qbr8jc/nodejs_finally_prefers_ipv6_addresses_over_ipv4/

You can bypass this in following ways:

1. use an hardcoded ip4 adress like 127.0.0.1
2. disable ip6 support in linux: see https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-linux
3. configure node to use IP4 adresses first. See [ECONNREFUSED when making a request to localhost using fetch in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72390154/econnrefused-when-making-a-request-to-localhost-using-fetch-in-node-js)

```
import dns from 'node:dns';
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');
```

If somebody can tell why IP6 does not (always?) works in the latest versions of nodejs. I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: It's not that IP6 doesn't work in more recent versions of Node.js, it's that the DNS result order is not always consistent, so it's possible for the client and server to both specify `localhost` and then have the server listening on IP4 and the client listening on IP6, or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading Node.js from v18 to v16 resolved the issue.